# setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener deprecated

Tags: java, android, bottombar

Currently I am working on an app which has a bottom navbar with three menu items. I had used `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener()` for items being clicked. but now iam facing issue that the method has been depreciated.

- App Language: `Java`
- Issue: `'setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)' is deprecated`

Is there any way to resolve it? is is there any better alternative than `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener()` method.

Comment: its not deprecated https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView#setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)

Answer (score 73):

Its deprecated according to github sources: [BottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView.java#L223)

In its comment you can read:

```
@deprecated Use {@link NavigationBarView#setOnItemSelectedListener(OnItemSelectedListener)}
   *     instead.
```

so use [NavigationBarView.setOnItemSelectedListener](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/cd5c2cc03ff30eb3f6c6959ffbc0c173ec63c089/lib/java/com/google/android/material/navigation/NavigationBarView.java#L371) from its base class:

```
  /**
   * Set a listener that will be notified when a navigation item is selected. This listener will
   * also be notified when the currently selected item is reselected, unless an {@link
   * OnItemReselectedListener} has also been set.
   *
   * @param listener The listener to notify
   * @see #setOnItemReselectedListener(OnItemReselectedListener)
   */
  public void setOnItemSelectedListener(@Nullable OnItemSelectedListener listener) {
    selectedListener = listener;
  }
```

Also see this [commit](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/720088c5c2462dbaaa90490bca04bb3bbdc708b1)

as it explains confusion about this change:

> The listeners were deprecated in favor of
> `NavigationBarView#OnItemSelectedListener` and
> `NavigationBarView#OnItemReselectedListener`, but deprecation
> documentation was never added, so it's unclear what developers should
> use instead.

Comment: I tried it. it works fine, Thanks. but the speed of switching between nav items gets a bit slower than `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`. any suggestions to improve it? Anyways thanks for the help

Comment: maybe add empty listener to setOnItemReselectedListener, this way your listener in setOnItemSelectedListener will not get called when item is re-selected

Answer (score 53):

you can try `setonItemSelectedListener`. It is working same as `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener()`[tested in android 11]

```
bnv.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            switch(id){
              //check id
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

**Kotlin:**

```
bnv.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
            }
            true
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

We can use `setOnItemSelectedListener` instead of `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener` and
`setOnItemReselectedListener` instead of `setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener`

```
navView.setOnItemSelectedListener {
    // do something
    true
}

// In case the default menu can be the first menu 
// Should set the default selected menu BETWEEN setOnItemSelectedListener and setOnItemReselectedListener. 
// It will make setOnItemSelectedListener fired when you launch app. 

// If you set default menu AFTER setOnItemReselectedListener. 
// Then setOnItemReselectedListener will fired when you launch app
navView.selectedItemId = R.id.navigation_home


navView.setOnItemReselectedListener {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use in Kotlin

```
buttmNav.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
        }
        true
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using setOnItemSelectedListener in place of setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener?

Answer (score 4):

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        displayfragment(new FragmentHome());

    }

    private void displayfragment(Fragment fragment) {

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_area, fragment).commit();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.nav_home:
                fragment = new FragmentHome();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_fav:
                fragment = new FavouriteFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_set:
                fragment = new FragmentSetting();
                break;

            default:
                fragment = new FragmentHome();
                break;

        }
        displayfragment(fragment);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what your solution is.

Comment: setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener is deprecated use this instead 
setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

Answer (score 1):

kotlin:
use  setOnItemSelectedListener

```
    bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item: MenuItem ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                 R.id. ... -> {
                    Add your code
                 true
            }
            
            else ->
                true
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Now You Should Use this

```
**`setOnItemSelectedListener`**
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 viewBindingMainActivity.navView.setOnItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
            if (menuItem.itemId != R.id.navigation_home) {
                Add your code
                false
            } else {
                Add your code
                true
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

**Add below line in your code**
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).