# bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener is deprecated

Tags: deprecated, bottomnavigationview

I'm Working with bottomNavigationView and now stuck at this point I want to use setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener but it is deprecated. Anyone can guide what I should use instead.
Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener depreciated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68021770/setonnavigationitemselectedlistener-depreciated)

Answer (score 0):

Use the monitoring method of the parent component

Comment: This answer needs clarity; how do you do that in code?