# Bottom Navigation view icon change not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-drawable, bottomnavigationview, android-icons

I want to change to icons of the bottom navigation view as we switch items.

[image]

I have light blue icons and dark blue icons for selected items.
I am using selector drawable for each navigation item but I see the images like below in grey as inactive and blue as active

[image]

Here is my code

bottom_nav_menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home_icon_selector"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_scheduler"
        android:icon="@drawable/schelduler_icon_selector"
        android:title="@string/title_scheduler" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_favourites"
        android:icon="@drawable/favourites_icon_selector"
        android:title="@string/title_favourites" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/settings_icon_selector"
        android:title="@string/title_settings" />
</menu>
```

home

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_20"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_20"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_20"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_20"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_8"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_navigation_background"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_color_selector"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

And selectors

scheduler selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/qa_scheduler_inactive" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_scheduler_blue" android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

Settings selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/qa_settings_inactive" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_settings_blue" android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

Favorites selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/qa_favorites_inactive" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_favourites_blue" android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

Home Selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/qa_home_inactive" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_home" android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

Activity code

```
    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_scheduler, R.id.navigation_favourites, R.id.navigation_settings))
    //  setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please help...

Edit :
I am using following drawables

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YvmNTMXRuu6J9MXJadpaV6SWptNKm7Vj?usp=sharing)

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ggEAXRukMLbdzvi86ElwSbQdFD3yntcn?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason of this issue is that there is always a value for `app:itemIconTint`, even if it is not used, it takes the default values of the primary/accent colors.

So to solve your problem you need to explicitly disable this with:

```
val btmNav = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)
navView.itemIconTintList = null
```

[image]

**Although I do recommend another thing:**

The icons are already the same icons in checked/unchecked states, but with different tint colors. If these icons are vectors, then you can just tint colors using a selector in `app:itemIconTint`, and use a single version of the icon without needing to duplicate the resources:

icon_color_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#2596CD" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="#84D0F4" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

And apply that:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    ...
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/icon_color_selector"
```

And keep the menu items only with icons not the selectors, for instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home_icon"  //<<<<< icon not selector
        android:title="@string/title_home" />

    ....

</menu>
```

**UPDATE:**

As you are using navigation architecture components, make sure to have the same ids in the `bottomNavView` menu that matches the corresponding ones in the `navGraph` of the `bottomNavView` fragments.

In case you don't use a `navGraph` for the `bottomNavView` fragments, then you can't use `navView.setupWithNavController(navController)`

Here is with your drawable icon

[image]

Comment: but I dont want to change just color of icon. the icons are different for selected and default  one.

Comment: @Sid Then you can go for `btmNav.itemIconTintList = null`

Comment: I tried but after that the default icon is set right which I wanted but for selected icon it shows white.

Comment: @Sid Which type of icons do you use .. Are they XML drawables? I still couldn't reproduce the issue.. Please check the gif in the answer

Comment: please check edited question given link for one of the drawbles used for selected and default. @Zain

Comment: @Sid Please check updated answer, hopefully your issue can be resolved now

Comment: @Sid Any thoughts upon this update.. I am willing to help further if you still encounter issues

Comment: hi sorry could not work for 2 days.. I did not get the answer shall I not use navView.setupWithNavController(navController)? then how bottom navigation will work with fragments?

Comment: No you should use `navView.setupWithNavController(navController)` in case the individual fragments of the `BottomNavView` are managed by a navigation graph.

Comment: Yes then I am using same.

Comment: My fragments are in navigation graph and that is passed to bottomNavView as navgraph. still Not getting the icons I want to show. How u did in that video?

Comment: I have no special code other than that shared..I think there is something probably in theme that makes yours didn't work.. can you share a demo so that i can figure it out

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess, but maybe this line here:

```
app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_color_selector"
```

is interfering with the colors of your drawables? If your drawables have the right colors (light blue/dark blue) they should work with your current selectors.

Alternatively, check that you don't set `app:itemIconTint` for the bottom-nav some other way, eg through a theme or programmatically!

Comment: I tried removed that line so now its all icons showing in grey color and selected to white

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using using selector like @Chris said or you can do it dynamically by using `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener{}`

update - For changing icons , you can just brute force by changing the current `item.icon` to filled and others to unfilled icon , see [here](https://github.com/sarafanshul/Habbit/blob/8aa5f22c41492b5823066c19550c40287dfbfa80/app/src/main/java/com/projectdelta/habbit/ui/insight/InsightsActivity.kt#L28) to get a gist of it (don't copy its for tabLayout).

```
navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item -> 
            // change  the icon to filled icon
            true
        }
```

It seems so that listner is depreciated so refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68024338/11718077)

Comment: this is showing deprecated. and how to change icons in this?