# BottonNavigationView Icon not changing on back press

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, android-navigation

I am using navigation component for bottom navigation component.

```
bottomNavbar.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

now this is working fine but when I hit the back button, it is returning to the home page but the icon is not changing, it is stuck in the previous selected fragment. I have three fragments and I have implemented navbar separately in all those fragments, here's the code for those three fragments.

settings fragment

```
val bottomNavbar = view.findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavbar)
bottomNavbar.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

search fragment

```
    val bottomNavbar = view.findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavbarSearch)
    bottomNavbar.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

chat fragment

```
val bottomNavbar = view.findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavbar)
    bottomNavbar.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

here search fragment is my home fragment.

Is there a mistake in my implementation or should I just switch to the old way of implementing bottom navigation view.

any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure to have the same ids in the bottomNavView menu that matches
> the corresponding ones in the navGraph of the bottomNavView fragments.

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68915308/16498927) answer

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32944636)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have added BottomNavigationView on all three fragments which should ideally be on Activity's view below your fragment/FragmentContainerView where you have defined your `navGraph`.

To fix it you need to remove BottomNavigationView from all 3 fragments and add it on Activity using the following basic structure.

Activity XML structure:

```
<constriantLayout>
    <fragment/> //with navGraph
    <bottomNavigationView/>
</constraintLayout>
```

and onCreate of Activity use the code setting up BottomNavigationView

```
val bottomNavbar = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavbar)
bottomNavbar.setupWithNavController(navController)
```